# Apply for Bulgarian residence permit after marrying a Bulgarian woman?

Tags: resident-permit, marriage, bulgaria, egyptian-citizens

I have a Bulgarian girlfriend and we are going to marry but am now in Egypt. What's the best solution to go to Bulgaria and marry her or she come to Egypt and then apply for D visa and then travel to Bulgaria and apply for residence? If I marry her in Egypt what requirements for me and her to make sure that I will get the D visa?

Comment: Please split the question into multiple parts